# Transparent proxy to original type

Tags: c#, marshalbyrefobject, context-bound

I have an run time object of type {System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy} which is created from an instance of class which is inherited from ContextBoundObject. This class raise an event to some other object, I need to convert this proxy object to original object. All objects are in default AppDomain on single system.

```
public abstract class ObjectBase : ContextBoundObject, IObjectBase
{
}

public IMessageSink GetObjectSink(MarshalByRefObject o, IMessageSink next)
        {
            _context = (ObjectBase)o;// as ObjectBase; does not give any error but type remains 
/// transparent proxy in VS watch window.
// no property to get the  underlying type of the proxy
             return _aspect;
        }
```

How to convert them into original object? Why proxy is cretaed if running on same memory

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `RealProxy` instance for the transarent proxy by calling [`MarshalServices.GetRealProxy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.remotingservices.getrealproxy.aspx), but getting the server object reference is then harder because the default `RealProxy` only has non-public members exposing this reference (a protected method [`GetUnwrappedServer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy.getunwrappedserver.aspx) and an internal property `UnwrappedServerObject`). You can either get to those if the `RealProxy` is implemented by yourself or via reflection (if you have enough trust to perform this).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't get the actual reference to an Context bound object. Evan you get the reference using reflection/internal API you will get unexpected behavior (cause you break the rules).
You can get more insides about context object using google.

I think you have an issue in your actual architecture/design. You can not have an object to be "agile" and "context bound" at the same time. A solution is to split your big object in 2 (one context bound and another agile, and hold a reference(s) between them).

So when you get the reference of the "agile" one (which inherits from MArshallByRefObject) into the creation AppDomain you get the real object reference, not a proxy. (this is the MarshallByRefObject definition)